# Google Puppeteer not fetching all third-party cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, puppeteer, headless-browser, cookieserve

```
Network.getAllCookies
```

#
Returns all browser cookies. Depending on the backend support, will return detailed cookie information in the cookies field.

```
RETURN OBJECT
cookies

array Cookie
Array of cookie objects.
```

[image]

[Chrome Dev tool Guide](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-getAllCookies)

```
    (async() => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('https://stack.com', {waitUntil : 'networkidle2' });
      // tried params like this as well
      // {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0}
      // {waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0}
      // {waitUntil: 'domContentLoaded', timeout: 0}

      // Here we can get all of the cookies
      console.log(await page._client.send('Network.getAllCookies'));

    })();
```

Not returning all cookies - Any other function to get cookies set by third-party scripts in the site.?

Comment: I don't see any reason ( and I might be wrong ) why would you think it would be possible , as 3'rd party cookies can only be read by their own domain

Comment: @RoyiNamir While submitting this URL in cookiemetrix, its getting 3 cookies - but puppeteer returns empty :(

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked. It showed me the third-party cookies for a domain. The domain in your code does not set any third-party cookies for me.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf The real website has coudflare cookie ( _cfduid ), because the site requesting to ipapi site. Puppeteer cant catch that :(

Answer (score 2):

If you're on macOs you can use the NPM package `chrome-cookies-secure` to pull them from your hard-disk. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-cookies-secure)

My related answer on a different post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55630524/10732370).